# How to set Placeholder text alignment as center in windows phone 8.1 Textbox

Tags: xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8.1

I want my Place holder text alignment as center in WP8.1 Textbox control I have following code but it is not working .

```
<TextBox IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"  PlaceholderText="Username" x:Name="email" TextAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
```

I have use `TextAlignment="Center"` but it align only text which I have enter not Placeholder Text

Comment: check this link http://www.rudijvr.com/windows-phone-8-1-rt-custom-placeholder-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible directly by setting up any property.You need to alter style of Textbox. Refer to the code below:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinWidth">51</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinHeight">34</x:Double>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">2.5</Thickness>
        <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
        <x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">20.26</x:Double>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlThemePadding">7,0.8,8,0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlMarginThemeThickness">0,9.5,0,9.5</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness">0,0,0,4.8</Thickness>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush"
                         Color="Transparent" />
        <x:Double x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeOpacity">0.8</x:Double>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1"
               TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                    Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                    Value="NoWrap" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode"
                    Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode"
                    Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
                    Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                             To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                             To="0"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Grid.Row="1" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                              Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}"
                                              Grid.Row="0"
                                              Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}" />
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                          HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                          IsTabStop="False"
                                          IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                          IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                          IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                          MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"
                                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                          VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                          ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                            FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
```